# Does the conjugate symmetry property of the Fourier series coefficients only hold for purely real input signals?

Tags: series, fourier

I'm learning out the Fourier series and trying to price conjugate symmetry for a genetic input signal but I'm finding that this property only holds for a purely real signal signal. Is this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it only holds for real-valued signals. If you consider the complex Fourier coefficients of the \$T\$-periodic function \$f(t)\$

$$c_n=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf(t)e^{-j2\pi nt/T}dt\tag{1}$$

then the complex conjugated coefficients are given by

$$c_n^*=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf^*(t)e^{j2\pi nt/T}dt\tag{2}$$

and, consequently,

$$c_{-n}^*=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf^*(t)e^{-j2\pi nt/T}dt\tag{3}$$

which is only equivalent to (1) if \$f(t)=f^*(t)\$, i.e. if \$f(t)\$ is real-valued.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to think of it is the Fourier series of a real signal is the sum of a bunch of cosine waves with different amplitudes and phases:

$$f(t) = a_0/2 + \sum_{n=1}^{N} a_n \cos (2\pi n/N (t + \phi_n))$$

And since

$$\cos(x) = \frac{e^{ix} + e^{-ix}}{2}$$

We can write this as

$$f(t) = \sum_{n=-N}^{N} a_n e^{i2\pi n/N (t+\phi_n)}$$

So the conjugate symmetry just comes from this way of expressing the cosine wave. Once could just write down the amplitudes and phases of the cosine waves but the complex exponential form is more convenient as it permits easy algebraic operations.